# Was my AWS ELB SSL connection vulnerable to HeartBleed

Tags: security, ssl, amazon-web-services, openssl, heartbleed-bug

I have an Elastic Load Balancer on AWS that does NOT terminate the SSL connection on the Load Balancer. Was my connection vulnerable to the HeartBleed bug before Amazon patched the ELB service?

My understanding is that only connections that terminated the SSL on the Load Balancer were affected. Can anyone confirm this?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about software versions, administration and patching. Server Fault has quite a few questions on the topic: http://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/heartbleed.

Comment: I would agree. I can't find an easy way to move it though. It should probably have been on serverfault or security.stackexchange.com

Comment: Shaun - don't worry about it. Its part of the normal process on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you instead terminate SSL on your own instances? If so then you need to look at the version of OpenSSL on those systems as they might be vulnerable to heartbleed.

Comment: We terminated the connection on IIS so OpenSSL was not involved past the Load Balancer.

Comment: Ok, yes in that case you are not vulnerable.